# Tracking changes to db fields while using ORM

Tags: java, database, orm, jpa

I want to track the changes made to every column in a particular table. I thought of storing the changes in another table with the following columns: `id, field, and data` where `field` (string value) is the column in the target table that has been altered and `data` is the new value of that field.

When returning the data set, I thought of retrieving the original data from the target table and the changed values from the table tracking changes, then using java's reflection capabilities to set the changed fields' values to the newest changed value.

Based on the above I have the following questions:

1. Does my approach makes sense? Is there a better way to achieve the desired results?
2. I'm using JPA 2 to handle ORM, are there any ORM features that can be helpful in achieving the end goal?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check Hibernate envers and Eclipselink historical session for entity auditing.. 
JPA 2.0 spec does not have anything related to entity auditing..

Comment: If you are using Hibernate, you should definitely check out envers. It can easily be integrated using hibernate's event mechanism and doesn't require much effort to be set up. Envers is quite powerful and can handle auditing of complete object graphs. In addition it makes querying history data easy.

Comment: & @Thomas: Since I'm using hibernate as the underlying implementation I looked into Envers and it does exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine. You may need many "data" fields to cover various data types (e.g date, text, longtext).

What I do to solve this problem (but also easily provide rollback capabilities) is to use [xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) and a text diff engine. I use xstream to grab an xml snapshot of the pojo, then apply the user's edit and then grab another. I diff the two snapshots and store the diff text. Also with some effort I can pretty print the modification in a wiki style.

Comment: This is what I am thinking. Which text diff engine did you use? Is it available in Java? If the xml output from xstream is over 1MB, how about the performance? Thank you.